# What neural network can I use to unmerge numbers?

Tags: mnist

I am working on a hobby project where I superimpose two different samples of two different numbers from the MNIST dataset.

However, I'm stuck at what model I could use. I tried messing around with autoencoders for this.

Is there some article or paper which could possibly guide in the right direction as I didn't find anything relevant?

[image: Two MNIST numbers merged]

For example, first one is 0 and 5, second is 5 and 6, third is 2 and 0, fourth is 1 and 3 and the last one is 3 and 6.

As you can see from the images that such a task is difficult for humans as well which makes me curious if a computer could notice patterns that we can not in order to perform better.

Comment: There is a comment from Andrew Ng, that say that to jauge the feasibility of a task by today ML, one must ask if it feasible by a human in less than a second. It seems rather difficult to me.

Comment: Yes, I remember! This makes me even more interested about when computers start to out-perform humans.